# How to add special tags to XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, documentation, doxygen

I'm trying to make `doxygen` work for `C#` since I've used to document my libraries and `C/C++` file.
In order to stay consistent with the environment, I want to make custom `XML` tags for example :

```
<Copyright> 
Copyright(c) to production firm all rights are reserved 2019
</Copyright>
```

and then It should output something like it does for \copyright using C/C++ markup.
Also, some basic information about the file documented ... it just like applying the same `C/C++` layout for the `C#` files.
I explored some feature like ALIASES, but doesn't seem to work properly for me or that I'm missing something. And it seems that `doxygen` don't bother itself matching documentation using the file containing documentation but rather using the tree coming from namespaces(packages) all the way through the local members of a Class.

Comment: In your question it looks to me that you have multiple issues, especially the part "/... don't bother itself matching documentation using the file containing documentation but rather using the tree coming from namespaces(packages)..) is unclear an example would certainly help here. Please entangle these issues into separate questions. The `ALIASES` is for creating custom commands (so with `\` or `@`). For constructs like `<copyright>...</copyright>` there is in doxygen no mechanism. Maybe it is worth writing an enhancement issue in the doxygen issue tracker

Comment: great to see a reponse for you, I believe you are right @albert, the tags I made provided an inconsistant behavior, Though i did manage to get Aliases combaning the HTML XML tags e.g : <copyright> = <par><b> Copyright: </b></par>.
Thus I guess a proper way to stay compatible with Doxygen, is to use Markdown for commun sections.